# How to remove href from last breadcrumb?

Tags: breadcrumbs

I'm altering breadcrumbs using the `theme_menu_breadcrumb_alter` function and was wondering what can I do to make the last breadcrumb **non-clickable** (i.e. it should be just text, not a link).

I tried making the `href` value to an empty string but that just returns a link to the base URL.

**How can I do this?**

Comment: Could you explain why would you want that? And have you considered altering (or at least inspecting) it's tpl file?

Comment: sure, since i'm on that page I don't need to make that last breadcrumb clickable

Comment: That's not always true. For example if there are filters on page, or content that changes in response to user's actions, clicking last breadcrumb element is a way to start clean. Also, it's convenient point to copy link location from, if access to address bar is somehow problematic (some mobile browsers for example). So it has some uses. And even if unneeded - does it really *bother* you?

Comment: very true, the question is what if my client wants me to ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If anyone else is looking for this, here is one way to solve it:

In `template.php` add the following function

```
function theme_breadcrumb($variables){
    // get an array with all the breadcrumbs (and their html)
    $breadcrumb = $variables['breadcrumb'];

    // remove the html from the last one and put it into new variable
    $cur_page_brdcrmb = strip_tags(end($breadcrumb));

    //remove the last element from the original breadcrumb array
    array_pop($breadcrumb);

    // add our html free breadcrumb to the array
    $breadcrumb[] = $cur_page_brdcrmb;

    // build the output and return it
    $output = '<div class="breadcrumb">' . implode(' » ', $breadcrumb) . '</div>';
    return $output;
}
```